# Обтекание текста вокруг круглого элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать обтекание текста вокруг круглого элемента?

Вот сама картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
p {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
}

.img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p><img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1cR.png" /> Земля – чудесная планета, ее природа разнообразна. Природа нашей планеты – это совокупность каждого элемента: физических естественных и материальных. Природой можно называть только то, что создавалось без непосредственного участия человека. Природа также представляет собой все физические, биохимические процессы на планете, а также жизнь в целом. Люди также являются частью природы, однако их зачастую рассматривают отдельно. В основном понятие «природа» относится только к животному миру и неживой природе. Обобщить понятием природы можно совокупность растений и животных, а иногда и явления неживого мира, которые напрямую влияют на живые организмы. Естественная среда обитания тех или иных организмов также считается природой. Это может быть экологическая система, представители животного, растительного миров, объекты вроде гор и склонов и так далее. Все объекты, которые не были затронуты человечеством, можно причислять к природным. Также места, сохраненные в первозданном виде, считаются природными объектами.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, добавить свойство CSS `Shapes`. Вот пример:

*Но лучшим решением, на мой взгляд, было бы решение на JavaScript*

```css
p {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
}

.img {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: url('https://yoksel.github.io/Sandbox/img/demo/circle-with-shadow.png');
  shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
  shape-margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p><img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1cR.png" /> Земля – чудесная планета, ее природа разнообразна. Природа нашей планеты – это совокупность каждого элемента: физических естественных и материальных. Природой можно называть только то, что создавалось без непосредственного участия человека. Природа также представляет собой все физические, биохимические процессы на планете, а также жизнь в целом. Люди также являются частью природы, однако их зачастую рассматривают отдельно. В основном понятие «природа» относится только к животному миру и неживой природе. Обобщить понятием природы можно совокупность растений и животных, а иногда и явления неживого мира, которые напрямую влияют на живые организмы. Естественная среда обитания тех или  иных организмов также считается природой. Это может быть экологическая система, представители животного, растительного миров, объекты вроде гор и склонов и так далее. Все объекты, которые не были затронуты человечеством, можно причислять к природным. Также места, сохраненные в первозданном виде, считаются природными объектами.</p>
```

Comment: Где можно узнать про новые методы CSS? Более 2х лет работаю, но не знаю таких методов, многое подчерпнул для себя глядя на ответы участников SO